# Nesting If Condition VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Can I nest `if` conditions with msgboxes? I use a lot of concatenations in the msgbox syntax including variables.

```vb
If Variable1 <> Variable2 Then 'then i want the below message box to appear 
    If MsgBox("Some text Here " & Variable1 & " Some Text here " & Variable3.Offset(0, 1).Value & " Some text here", vbOKCancel, "Title", vbOKCancel) = vbCancel Then Exit Sub '<--this is what i want to achieve if cancel button is pressed 
End If
```

At the moment I get

> Invalid procedure, call or argument error

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: The error is because `....vbOKCancel, "Title", vbOKCancel)` is off (the 2nd `vbOkCancel` is not a valid *helpfile* argument). Check the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/msgbox-function) for more details on the arguments.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: The question is how can I exit sub once the cancel button is pressed at the moment i get Invalid procedure, call or argument error with the code above

Comment: Really really suggest that you break the *prompt* portion of the MsgBox into its own variable. That `MsgBox` line is *way* too long and it's obscuring the cause of the error.

Comment: Thank You BigBen you were correct I have used it the vbOK/cancel twice hence the error. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not test this but I think this is what you are looking for
Make sure to follow the correct syntax for MsgBox `MsgBox (prompt, [ buttons, ] [ title, ] [ helpfile, context ])`

Also if a line is too long format it to multiple lines, it will be easier to understand and/or find an issue with your code.

```
Dim response
If Variable1 <> Variable2 Then 'then i want the below message box to appear 
    response = MsgBox("Some text Here " & Variable1 & " Some Text here " & Variable3.Offset(0, 1).Value & " Some text here", vbOKCancel, "Title")
    If response = vbOKCancel Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
End If
```

Comment: phil652 declaring response seems to be the best solution. This worked like a magic thanks for this